# Canon printer: How to bypass ink cartridge detection and use only the scanner?

Tags: printer, canon-pixma

I have a **Canon Pixma MP287** printer which has color printing as well as scanner facilities. I do not use the printing facility and the cartridges are now empty (and probably dry).

**Desired Outcome**: I wish to use the scanner only. I wish to bypass the automatic ink cartridge detection when I power on the printer and use the device as a scanner only.

**Current status**: The printer is displaying a `P02` status code (*error has occurred transporting the cartridge carriage*).

**What I have tried**: When I power on the printer, I hold down the `stop` button for 5-10 seconds to prevent the detection - but, this is not working.

**Info I believe is NOT relevant**: *the OS I use, the page I am trying to scan* (unless there is an option in the drivers to prevent that)

I hope someone must have used this exact model and will have come across the very same scenario.

Answer (score 1):

These are the options I know of:

- Try to hold down the Stop button for longer time
- In the Maintenance tab of the printer's properties, search for an option for
  disabling the ink level warning indicator
- Buy some cheap OEM ink cartridges.

Comment: I have tried many deltas of bullet 1. bullet 2 I will look into. bullet 3 is out of scope